# In semiconductors, what will push an stable electron of the bonds to try to fill the holes quickly?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

[image]

it was mentioned in Razavi electronics course that when holes are created in the intrinsic silicon lattice , electrons from bond will go faster to fill it. But why? what would push it to do so if it was stable.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing pushes a bonding electron to fill a vacancy, but nothing holds it back either - the orbital that it occupies and the empty one are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is talking about semiconductors that above 0K. This means that there is heat energy in this system. The heat energy causes some electrons to get excited and break free from the regular silicon lattice. Thats why electron are always bouncing around and creating and filling holes. There is nothing that is compelling them to from the bond to go and fill a hole, but the heat energy in the system will mean that there is more kinetic energy in the electrons which will be used to break free from the bonds. And after having broken free, there is nowhere else *relatively* stable for it to go other than the existing holes.
Hope this solves your problem.